# Writing XML to file from JSP page. Maintaining encoding for XML (non-english language)

Tags: java, xml, jsp, scriptlet

I've got a JSP page which will be run daily which first:

Retrieves XML from a database field using:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver());
```

The ResultSet `rs.getString(todayXML);` contains the XML.

I then want to write it to an XML file for which I have the following code:

```
  currentXML = rs.getString("todayXML");
  String docID = rs.getString("docID");

  //File creation
  String file = application.getRealPath("/") + "/xmls/"+docID + ".xml";

  out.println("<p>Found document: " + docID + "</p>");
  PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(file);
  printout.print(currentXML);
  printout.close();
```

This is all run in a while loop that's going through the ResultSet.

This all works fine except the XML is courrupted: 
"An invalid character was found in text content" is the read error I get from IE. I know this is because the XML contains foreign characters.

I think this has something to do with storing the XML in a String (currentXML) which encodes it without preserving the characters.

I'm fairly new to Java and JSP in general, so a quick method would be ideal.
Whether to escape the XML or store it in a type a bit more forgiving.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what type has the XML database field?

Answer (score 0):

For future programmers:

Its fairly long-winded but I managed to use the UTF8 encoding when writing to a file with PrintWriter.

Code:

```
PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8")));
      printout.print(currentXML);
      printout.close();
```

**Edit:**

Must be going blind; you can encode it with UTF8 from print writer..

```
PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF8");
```